# DB design - store selection in database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm working on a web application where I need to do some research before I implement the database. I hope you can help me make some good decisions before I start to code.

Today i have a database that among other things contains about two million contacts in a table

**Contact:**
cid, name, phone, address, etc...

Users of the application can search the contact table based on different criteria, and get a list of contacts.

Users are stored i a separate database table

**User:** uid, name, email, etc...

Now I want to make the users able to store a search result as a selection. The selection has to be a list of cid's representing every contact in the search result the user got. When the selection is stored, a user can open the selection and add notes, statuses etc to the different contacts in the selection.

My first thought is to make a selection table and a selection-contact mapping table like this:

**Selection:** sid, name, description, uid, etc

**SelectionContactMap:** sid, cid, status, note, etc...

With an average selection size between 1 000 and 100 000 contacts, and several thousand users  storing many selections, I see that the SelectionContactMap table is going to grow very big very fast.

The database is MySql and the application is written in PHP. I'm on a limited budget so I can not throw unlimited hardware on the task.

I'm I on the wrong way here?

Do you have any suggestions to solve this the best possible way?

- Other database?
- MySql specific suggestions, table type etc?
- Other database design?
- Any comments and suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

-- Tor Inge

Comment: how often you need to update the users selected contacts? Is that gonna happens each day for a user to update his selection or it's a one time a month task? Also how often you're gonna load this data? 10-times a day per user or once a week?

Comment: The users will work on a daily basis on his selection. Changing statuses and adding notes to contacts in the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Question: What happens if the results of the query change - eg: a selected contact no longer has the chosen attribute or a new contact gets added?

If the answer is "The result set should be updated" - then you want to store the criteria in the database, not the results themselves.

If you need to cache the results for a period of time, this may be better handled by the application, not the database.

Comment: I need to store the selection exactly as it was when the search was executed. Therefore I can not just store the search parameters.

Comment: @TorIngeSchulstad Then you're going to have to store a lot of data. :)